# Change event for a select is throwing a "jQuery is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JS code :**

```
function banChanged(){
    $("#BanReason").on("change",function(){
        if($(this).val() == "scrammer")
            $("#BanLength").val("1week");
    });
}
```

**HTML code :**

```
<select id="BanReason" onchange="banChanged()">
    <option value="hack">Hack</option>
    <option value="badlang">Bad Language</option>
    <option value="scrammer">Scrammer</option>
</select>

<select id="BanLength">
    <option value="1day">1 Day</option>
    <option value="2days">3 Days</option>
    <option value="1week">1 Week</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript is a different location. When I click in select to change the value, I get this "is not a function" error. The script works inline, but it needs to be loaded in a `<script type="text/javascript" src="./test.js"></script>` tag.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#BanReason").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "scrammer")
      $("#BanLength").val("1week");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="BanReason">
  <option value="hack">Hack</option>
  <option value="badlang">Bad Language</option>
  <option value="scrammer">Scrammer</option>
</select>

<select id="BanLength">
  <option value="1day">1 Day</option>
  <option value="2days">3 Days</option>
  <option value="1week">1 Week</option>
</select>
```

Also make sure jQuery is loaded before your script, and that the path to your script is correct. `./test.js` means that your script is in the same folder as your .html file.

Comment: @ Kerem Er.  Please accept the answer if it answers your question

Comment: What error are you receiving. If it's the same error. That means your jQuery is not loading make sure that <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Is in your .tel file before you include your other .j's file

Answer (score 1):

Remove the inline event attached by `onchange()` because you already attach the on change event in js code, also remove the function declaration leave just the content wraped by ready function, check example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#BanReason").on("change",function(){
    if($(this).val() === "scrammer")
      $("#BanLength").val("1week");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="BanReason">
  <option value="hack">Hack</option>
  <option value="badlang">Bad Language</option>
  <option value="scrammer">Scrammer</option>
</select>

<select id="BanLength">
  <option value="1day">1 Day</option>
  <option value="2days">3 Days</option>
  <option value="1week">1 Week</option>
</select>
```